# How to compare nested models in glmer ()

Tags: anova, lme4-nlme

I am testing random intercept models using the `glmer()` function in R.
I learned from my stat class I need to use FIML, not REML to compare nested models.
However, `glmer()` do not use either FIML or REML for model estimation, to my knowledge.
Then can I just use `anova()` to compare the different models?
I wonder if there are any other methods.